# Bevel inner edge issue

Tags: modeling, bevel

I'm not really sure what to call this, but here's a quick example of my problem:[image]

When beveling a corner edge loop, Blender fattens the inner edge instead of keeping it mostly the same width. I've tried to figure out how to fix this in vanilla Blender. I also have several popular addons and couldn't figure out how to resolve it with any of them either (HardOps, MESHmachine, MACHINE3tools). It seems really strange to me that there isn't a setting you can change in the default bevel tool, which makes me feel like I must be missing something.

EDIT: Assume the mesh is too complex to do this with Solidify (which is how I got the "Good" version for my example).

Thanks in advance for reading and responding!

Comment: Could you add some screenshots and more information of the objects/mesh that you are trying to bevel?... i just made a test and [this is my result](https://imgur.com/a/ZHStDP7)

Comment: @Emir That's the result I'm aiming for, but I'm trying to do it without using Solidify. On more complex models, it's not always practical or possible, so I'm trying to figure out how to do this using the default tool or addons. I'm pretty new to Blender and I've already run into this issue a surprising number of times, but I'm not sure exactly what to search for. Most people having bevel issues just failed to apply the scale.

Comment: @ As i mentioned, you need to add more information about the object that you are having problems and even images of that or  the specific moments where you found that issue. Without that information, everyone will be testing that with different objects with different results and different approaches, If you just said things like "Assume the mesh is complex" is not enough, because there are a lot of different meshes that are complex on its own way

Comment: @Emir What more information do you need? Without knowing the complexity of the mesh, I can clearly read in the question he wants to achieve the result on the right with the _Bevel Tool_ and not the _Solidify Modifier_. The answer posted here suggests trying different _Width Type_ settings, I've tried them all but none of them work as expected... and you don't even need a complex mesh for that.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i did not do my example with a solidify modifier, it's just a  bevel and the user said that "he is trying to do that on a more complex model" that's why i asked what kind of model is having issues with, if a simple Bevel is not working the main goal, then probably the model have something different.

Comment: @Emir Obviously Marty decided his answer wasn't the solution...? I had an image and a file in a comment which showed what I get when I bevel it. I would really like to know your bevel settings because I cannot achieve your result. Here is a file with some tests: [example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AQ9rubqsGSDFlrNsNctotRi0FlRGGo4S/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Wow. Thanks for being so thorough with your attempts. I'm glad I'm not crazy. After I posted this, I thought about creating some "guides" with extra segments to mark the intended bevel width, then bevel using percent mode set to 100%, then merge the overlapping verts. That will work in some cases, but may not be practical for all cases. Either way, it still seems really strange to me that this isn't a more common issue. Which, again, makes me think I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @Emir Normally, I'd agree that a specific example would help, but this issue doesn't require a specific example. It's an issue with literally any edge loop that you want to bevel. Whether you're beveling a bent triangular prism, a bent pipe, or something with a lot of grooves, I don't see an easy way to get the desired result. The image you provided is the desired result, but I did assume that you used solidify. If not how did you get there? (I'm not challenging, just curious because it may be the correct answer). Cheers.

Comment: @MaxWilliams It's actually bothering me for a long time, but I always thought it's just the way it i, I don't like that but have to accept it if you simply cannot do it. But when you post this question and people insist it does work I'm getting curious - maybe there is something I've been doing wrong all the time. Although I somehow understand why it can't work as expected, because we expect the Bevel Tool to treat the object as it it was something with a certain thickness to stay consistent. But all in all in the example they are both 90° corners - why should one be beveled than the other?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I'm still hoping there's a way to do it. I'm also surprised that one of the addons I mentioned doesn't fix this either. The trick I came up with does work though. It just takes a little bit of extra setup. I'm still hoping there's a better solution though.

Comment: I guess the Bevel tool cannot do this because it simply bevels edges. What we want is making it work like a Solidify or Contour tool - you see, if you have a tube with a width of 1 m, and there's a sharp 90° corner, the diagonal width there is sqrt(2) =1.4142... instead of 1 m. How should the Bevel tool "know" we want to transform the width to 1 m when it is 1.41 m at the bevel location?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Hmm. I'm not sure and I don't know nearly enough about the math or programming to make a script to handle it. I'm surprised that MESHmachine doesn't have a feature for this. Creating a set of edge loop guides and beveling to 100 percent will just have to work until I find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi unfortunately this is not possible in a more easier way as a option in the width settings, but here is the hack to achieve this using percent width option:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ERuOOM6eV3cWnDaDCIqdTVv44l5KkYzj/view?usp=sharing

Procedure:

Add two edge loops that must be completely straight/perpendicular to the adjacent edges near of the loop you are gonna bevel...Select the edge loop to bevel...Then press ctrl+b to bevel, add the desired segment count and left click to apply, then press F6 to open the bevel operator popover menu (or use if you like the same menu that appears in below left corner, that appears after you left clicked to apply the operation) and change the width type to percent, and tweak the percent slider amount to 100%...

And that's it basically...also the edge loops serve as a guide for the bevel operator to get the perfect round profile you need...

Comment: That's a trick I've used before. Unfortunately, it's harder to pull off with more complex geometry and doesn't allow you to remain non-destructive. It still has value for the times when it does work though!

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yep it doesnt work in modifier, only the manual way... i hope the devs may implement that algorithm to the bevel profile besides of the default one...